# How can I change the styles of the react-toastify popup message?

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I want to add my own custom style to the react-toastify message popup, depending on whether its success or error. So far I tried the following approach:

**toastify.js**

```
import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { css } from "glamor";


toast.configure({
    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
    autoClose: 3000,
    transition: Slide,
    pauseOnFocusLoss: false,
        className: css({
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }),
    bodyClassName: css({
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
    })
});

export default function (message, type, styles = {}) {
    switch (type) {
        case type === 'success':
            toast.success(message);
            break;

        case type === 'error':
            toast.error(message);
            break;

        case type === 'info':
            toast.info(message);
            break;

        case type === 'warn':
            toast.warn(message);
            break;
            
        default:
            toast(message);
            break;
    }
}
```

This is a function in which I define what type of message style toastify shows based on the type param. Then I call this function like this:

export default function ({params}) {
...
async function deleteTodo (id) {
try {
const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/delete-task/${id}`);

```
        toastifyMessage(res.data, 'success');
    } catch (error) {
        errorInfo(toastifyMessage(error, 'error'));
    }
}

return (
    <li className="menu-item">
        <i 
            className="fas fa-trash" 
            onClick={() => deleteTask(task._id)}
        ></i>
    </li>
);
```

}

And this is what I get:

[image]

I still get that white background. All I want is to remove the default styles and add my own for success and error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

for custom style react-toastify

[image][image]
[image]

css

```
.Toastify__toast--error {
    border: 1px solid #EB5757;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
    background: #FAE1E2 !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--error::after {
  content : url('../assets/images/svg/closeToast.svg'); // Your svg Path
  position: absolute;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left:265px;
  padding-top: 14px !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--error::before {
  content: url("../assets/images/svg/errorToast.svg");// Your svg Path
  position:relative; 
  z-index:100000;
  left:12px;
  top:6px;
}
.Toastify__toast--success {
  border: 1px solid #3A9EA5 !important;
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  background: #F0F9FA !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--success::before {
  content: url("../assets/images/svg/successToast.svg");// Your svg Path
  position:relative; 
  z-index:100000;
  left:12px;
  top:6px;
}
.Toastify__toast--success::after {
  content : url('../assets/images/svg/closeToast.svg');// Your svg Path
  position: absolute;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left:265px;
  padding-top: 14px !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--warning {
  border: 1px solid #E78326  !important;
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  background: #FADFC5 !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--warning::before {
  content: url("../assets/images/svg/warnToast.svg");// Your svg Path
  position:relative; 
  z-index:100000;
  left:12px;
  top:6px;
}  
.Toastify__toast--warning::after {
  content : url('../assets/images/svg/closeToast.svg'); // Your svg Path
  position: absolute;
  color: #E78326;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left:265px;
  padding-top: 14px !important;
}
.Toastify__toast-body {
  color: #444C63    ;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 25px !important;
} 
.Toastify__toast > button>  svg {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case (also a React app) I only needed to change:

- background color of warning and error
- progress bar color
- font

I found this to be the easiest & quickest solution. In my app's CSS file I overwrite the background-property in the default classes. I also define my own classes for toast body and the progress bar:

```
/* https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style/ */
.Toastify__toast--warning {
  background: #FFE8BC !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--error {
  background: #FCA7A9 !important;
}
.toastBody {
  font-family: "Atlas Grotesk Web", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #10171D; /* #10171D */
  font-size: 0.875rem !important;
}
.toastProgress {
  background: #333F48 !important;
}
```

To use my classes:

```
<ToastContainer
  progressClassName="toastProgress"
  bodyClassName="toastBody"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easest way to define a custom method, which can take the type of notification, content, and toast options. With the type of notification, you can pass different classNames to your custom content and override root toast component styles. Typescript example:

```
export enum NOTIFICATIONS_TYPES {
  SUCCESS = 'success',
  ERROR = 'error',
}

const NotificationStringContent: React.FunctionComponent<{
  content: string;
}> = ({ content }) => (
  <Typography component="p" variant="text-200">
    {content}
  </Typography>
);

export const showNotification = (
  type: NOTIFICATIONS_TYPES,
  content: string | React.ReactElement,
  options: ToastOptions = {}
) => {
  const toastContent = typeof content === 'string' ? (
    <NotificationStringContent content={content} />
  ) : (
    content
  );
  toast(toastContent, {
    className: classnames(styles.toast, {
      [styles.toastSuccess]: type === NOTIFICATIONS_TYPES.SUCCESS,
      [styles.toastError]: type === NOTIFICATIONS_TYPES.ERROR,
    }),
    ...options,
  });
};

const NotificationContainer: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
  <ToastContainer
    position="bottom-left"
    hideProgressBar
    closeButton={<NotificationCloseButton />}
    closeOnClick={false}
    pauseOnHover
  />
);

export default NotificationContainer;
```

Comment: Nice concept, I did something similar. However I'd suggest you at least mention that your example is in Typescript. Or provide the same example in plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
// promise is a function that returns a promise
export const withToast = (promise) => {
  toast.promise(
    promise,
    {
      pending: {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className="p-6 py-2 bg-green-400">
              <p className="mb-2">Your transaction is being processed.</p>
              <p>Hang tight... Just few more moments.</p>
            </div>
          );
        },
        icon: false,
      },
      success: {
        render({ data }) {
          return (
            <div>
              <p className="font-bold">
                Tx: {data.transactionHash.slice(0, 20)}...
              </p>
              <p>Has been succesfuly processed.</p>
            </div>
          );
        },
        // other options
        icon: "",
      },
      error: {
        render({ data }) {
          // When the promise reject, data will contains the error
          return <div>{data.message ?? "Transaction has failed"}</div>;
        },
      },
    },
    // configuration
    {
      closeButton: true,
    }
  );
};
```

When you need to use it:

```
  withToast(_purchase({ Id, value }));
```

Depending on `_purchase`, your app will show different messages with different styles